# IIS and external unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, unmanaged

I have a .NET C# WebAPI running under IIS and on my code I'm loading an external unmanaged DLL, I don't have the source code for it. The external DLL in turn tries to load another DLL so it's accessing the filesystem and it's assuming the second DLL is in the same folder as itself.

When I run the api as a self hosted app everything works, when I run the api as an hosted app in IIS I can load the external unmanaged DLL but I get a popup message informing the DLL failed to do something (what exactly is not clear). I'm assuming the DLL is unable to load its companion DLL. The popup message is generated by the DLL itself. The DLL doesn't create any log file

Using process monitor I can confirm my C# code is finding and loading the DLL

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Posting screenshot of error popup may be helpful. Hard to say but could be 32/64 bit issue. Can you please confirm against what platform those unmanaged dlls are built? Since you said companion dll is trying to access filesystem so it may also be permission issue. Check your app's app pool identity permissions.

Comment: @PankajKapare DLLs are 64bit, my api is 64bit as well. Unfortunately a screenshot doesn't help as it is a custom error message thrown by the DLL which basically means "couldn't init properly". How can I set the pool identity permission? could you please elaborate more?

Comment: By app pool identity what I meant was account under which app pool of your application is running. Check if that account has access to files and folders which it is trying to access/modify. Again this is just guess. May not be cause of error you are getting.

Comment: ok, how can I edit those permissions? where I should go? many thanks. Is it enough to give full permissions to "Everyone" to such folder?

Comment: In IIS select your application (WebApi). On right hand side pane of iis manager console select basic settings (link). There you will find which app pool is assigned to app. Then go to application pools (located top left corner of iis console). Check properties of app pool. You will find identity of app pool there. Once you get identity then in windows explorer right click on folder/files which dll is accessing then select properties and in security tab check if your app pool identity have required access. Hope that helps.